# SQL Server 'AS' alias unexpected syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've come across following T-SQL today:

```
select c from (select 1 union all select 1) as  d(c)
```

that yields following result:

```
c
-----------
1
1
```

The part that got me confused was **d(c)**

While trying to understand what's going on I've modified T-SQL into:

```
select c, b from (select 1, 2 union all select 3, 4) m(c, b)
```

which yields following result:

```
c           b
----------- -----------
1           2
3           4
```

It was clear that **d** & **m** are table reference while letters in brackets **c** & **b** are reference to columns.
I wasn't able to find relevant documentation on msdn, but curious if

1. You're aware of such syntax?
2. What would be useful use case scenario?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Exactly like you've used it; when using a derived table and the aliases of the columns aren't defined in it. 3 Does that *really* answer your question though?

Comment: @daleK question guide, it's not a rule just a guide, curious how you would display the result set including column names ? Result to text ? much uglier then the image I've posted

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever define hard looking ... Assumption that everybody would recognize derived table in posted sql of the bat is I believe behind your comment which might explain my difficulties in finding relevant documentation.

Comment: @Larnu IamDave's answer, answers my question (possibly poorly put) perfectly.

Comment: Images are even uglier to those using screen readers, @krul , and images of text are ugly to copy and paste into consumable text.

Comment: @larnu beauty is in the eye of beholder ... agree to disagree there

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/beauty-eye-beholder-message-recycled-paper-note-pinned-cork-board-concept-image-51988194.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately for you, @krul , you disagree with the FAQ which we do ask users to follow. Not doing so can easily result in downvotes or possibly close votes. If want to post images of text don't be "upset" if you get them; it was your choice to use content that warrants it. Usefulness > beauty (especially when beauty is in the eyes of the beholder and uselessness isn't).

Comment: @Larnu can you point me to exact rule that I've violated ?
And btw how did you diagnose my emotional state "upset"

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you read my question carefully you won't find any images of code/errors, so what's the rule I've violated ?

Comment: @krul the text I posted is verbatim from the question wizard when you ask a question, to repeat "please do not post images of code, data, error messages ..." note it says code, **date**, errors. And you only have to look at a few other questions in this tag to find some well formatted text data with column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already had comments that point you to the documentation of how derived tables work, but not to answer you question regarding useful use cases for this functionality.

Personally I find this functionality to be useful whenever I want to create a set of addressable values that will be used extensively in your statement, or when I want to duplicate rows for whatever reason.

An example of addressable values would be a much more compelx version of the following, in which the calculated values in the `v` derived table can be used many times over via more sensible names, rather than repeated calculations that will be hard to follow:

```
select p.ProductName
      ,p.PackPricePlusVAT - v.PackCost as GrossRevenue
      ,etc
from dbo.Products as p
    cross apply(values(p.UnitsPerPack * p.UnitCost
                      ,p.UnitPrice * p.UnitsPerPack * 1.2
                      ,etc
                      )
               ) as v(PackCost
                     ,PackPricePlusVAT
                     ,etc
                     )
```

and an example of being able to duplicate rows could be in creating an exception report for use in validating data, which will output one row for every `DataError` condition that the `dbo.Product` row satisfies:

```
select p.ProductName
      ,e.DataError
from dbo.Products as p
    cross apply(values('Missing Units Per Pack'
                      ,case when p.SoldInPacks = 1 and isnull(p.UnitsPerPack,0) < 1 then 1 end
                      )
                     ,('Unusual Price'
                      ,case when p.Price > (p.UnitsPerPack * p.UnitCost) * 2 then 1 end
                      )
                     ,(etc)
               ) as e(DataError
                     ,ErrorFlag
                     )
where e.ErrorFlag = 1
```

If you can understand what these two scripts are doing, you should find numerous examples of where being able to generate additional values or additional rows of data would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
select c from (select 1 union all select 1) as d(c)
```

is the same as

```
select c from (select 1 as c union all select 1) as d
```

In the first query you did not name the column(s) in your subquery, but named them outside the subquery,

In the second query you name the column(s) inside the subquery

If you try it like this (without naming the column(s) in the subquery)

```
select c from (select 1 union all select 1) as d
```

You will get following error

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'd'

This is also in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

As for the usage, some like to write it the first method, some in the second, whatever you prefer. It's all the same

Answer (score 2):

An observation: Using the table constructor `values` gives you no way of naming the columns, which makes it neccessary to use column naming after the table alias:

```
select * from
(values
     (1,2) -- can't give a column name here
    ,(3,4)
) as tableName(column1,column2) -- gotta do it here
```